# Selecting dynamic input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label>
       <input>
       <datalist></datalist>
       <a id="addspell" data-id="1"></a>
       <a></a>
       <p>
          <a>
             <select></select>
             <label>
                    <input name="championSpell[]">
             </label>
          </a>
       </p>
</label>
```

I would like to target in jquery from  are added dynamically. So I want to get the id of the last input with championSpell so I can increase data-id of the next one that will be added by 1.

```
alert( $('input[name="championSpell[]"]').data("id"));
```

Update 
This is what I'm using right now

```
 alert( $('input[name="championSpell[]"]:last').data("id"));
```

89.69.172.125/test.php Kinda works but there could add spell buttons so when you click add I would like to get :last from that input you can check in the link i've attached

Comment: "there could add spell buttons so when you click add I would like to get :last from that input" , When you click add means Add Spell , I would like to get :last from that input means ? which element you want ? can not get your question then.

Comment: its like subcategory you can have many champions and every champion can have multiple spells you can check it on the link ive attached and I want spells per champion to go 1,2,3,4,5 etc champion2 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc

Comment: Your code already working as per your requirements, I see it in Chrome browser and may be it show perfect, when you click on Add Spell one alert is open and it show count, and it is also increase  as per click. So, Is is browser issue or still I can not get your question ?

Comment: Check this picture http://imgur.com/U9IOS02

Answer (score 1):

How about using the selector `:last`  like:

```
alert( $('input[name="championSpell[]"]:last').data("id"));
```

> **`:last`** selects a single element by filtering the current jQuery collection and matching the last element within it

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('[name="championSpell[]"]').last().attr("id"));
```

last function returns the last element that matches.

https://api.jquery.com/last/

http://jsfiddle.net/dtpgb787/

**Update:** are you looking for something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/4b6f2nx2/

```
$('#addspell').click(function (e) {
    var cnt = $(this).data("id");
    $(this).data("id", cnt + 1);
    $('#container').append('<input type="text" id="dynamicInput' + (cnt+1) + '" value="' + (cnt+1) + '" />');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Updated BTW your HTML should really be cleaned up. There is no reason to have a select, label, and input nestled in an anchor.

Comment: That is not what I'm going for check the page I've just added your code with alert(cnt) it has to reset for new inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get dom elements using Jquery , Here you want to access last elements from your page having specific name so for that you can use

```
var varDomElement = $('input[name="championSpell[]"]:last');
```

Here in "varDomElement" you can get your element and after getting you can do what ever you want,

```
var domId = varDomElement.attr("id");
```

So, It will give you id from that dom.